# Select slices/ range of columns for each row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the problem:

```
import numpy
import pandas

dfl = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(30,10))
```

now, I want the following cells put in a data frame:

- For row 1: columns 3 to 6 (length = 4 cells),
- For row 2: columns 4 to 7 (length = 4 cells),
- For row 3: columns 1 to 4 (length = 4 cells),
- ect...

Each of these range is always 4 cells wide, but the start/end are different columns.

The row-wise start point are in a list `[3, 4, 1,...]` and so are the row-wise end points. The list of rows I'm interested in is also a list `[1, 2, 3]`.

Finally, `dfl` has an datetime-index which I would like to preserve
 (meaning the end result should be a data frame with indexes `dfl.index[1, 2, 3]`.

## Edit: range exceeds

Some of the entries of the vector of row-wise start points are too large (say a row-wise start point of 9 in the example matrix above). In those case, I just want all the columns from the row-wise start point and then as many NaN's as necessary to get the right shape (so since `9+4 > 10`, then the corresponding row of the result data frame should be `[9, 10, NaN, NaN]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create all those column indices and then [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) into the array data -

```
def extract_rows(dfl, starts, L, fillval=np.nan):
    a = dfl.values

    idx = np.asarray(starts)[:,None] + range(L)
    valid_mask = idx < dfl.shape[1]
    idx[~valid_mask] = 0

    val = a[np.arange(len(idx))[:,None],idx]
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(valid_mask, val, fillval))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [541]: np.random.seed(0)

In [542]: dfl = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(11,99,(3,10)))

In [543]: dfl
Out[543]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  55  58  75  78  78  20  94  32  47  98
1  81  23  69  76  50  98  57  92  48  36
2  88  83  20  31  91  80  90  58  75  93

In [544]: extract_rows(dfl, starts=[3,4,8], L=4, fillval=np.nan)
Out[544]: 
      0     1     2     3
0  78.0  78.0  20.0  94.0
1  50.0  98.0  57.0  92.0
2  75.0  93.0   NaN   NaN

In [545]: extract_rows(dfl, starts=[3,4,8], L=4, fillval=-1)
Out[545]: 
    0   1   2   3
0  78  78  20  94
1  50  98  57  92
2  75  93  -1  -1
```

Comment: Fantastic. It looks so simple now;). One question is there a way to prevent the largest entry of each row of `idx` from exceeding the number of colunms of `dfl`? I'm asking because I actually have that some of the entries of the vector of row-wise start points are too large (say `9` in the example above). In those case, I just want all the columns from the row-wise start point and then as many NaN's as necessary to get the right shape (so if 9+L > 10, then do `[9, 10, NaN, NaN]`

Answer (score 2):

Or we can using `.iloc` and `enumerate`

```
l=[3, 4, 1]
pd.DataFrame(data=[df.iloc[x:x+1,y:y+4].values[0] for x,y in enumerate(l)])
Out[107]: 
          0         1         2         3
0  1.224124 -0.938459 -1.114081 -1.128225
1 -0.445288  0.445390 -0.154295 -1.871210
2  0.784677  0.997053  2.144286 -0.179895
```

Comment: Sorry, what is `l` in `enumerate(l)`?

Comment: @user189035 sorry about that , that is the list you provided `l=[3, 4, 1]`